# High memory low cpu amazon instance required

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have some Java/Spring apps running on Amazon EC2 instances that use up considerable RAM but use hardly any CPU. At this point the memory is maxing out and I need to increase the memory. What's the best type of EC2 instance to change to? I'm currently using m3.large.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Memory Optimized R3](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/#memory-optimized) should satisfy you. This type provide lowest price point per 1 GB of RAM among Amazon offerings.

For $0.033 / hour more you will double your RAM (comparing `m3.large` vs `r3.large`) without sacrificing other resources.